# Use VLC to stream video to Android device

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, vlc

I try to use VLC to Streaming a video to my android phone
here is my code

```
 public class VideoMain extends Activity {
    VideoView myVideoView;   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_main);
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);        
        myVideoView.setVideoPath("http://140.118.208.220:8080");
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));   
}
```

and the I use VLC streaming wizard->streaming to network->myVideo->HTTP->MPEG2->FINISH

But it seem to not work at all

please help my solve this:)

Answer (score 0):

Android supports **3GPP (.3gp)** and **MPEG-4 (.mp4)** no MPEG-2 in video for more detail see [Android Developer Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).